# PyDev first input problems

Tags: python, pydev, read-write

So I'm trying to take an input and have my code treat it line-by-line, but I'm getting "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

The goal is to take each line of input, break it and run it through the code, and rewrite the answer to each line of the file. Sorry if this is clumsy, I've never had to use .in files before and although I've been reading a lot, I haven't understood it in context.

```
with open("C:\\Users\\mpaul_000\\Downloads\\a-small-practice.in", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        array.append(line)

#with open('C:\\Users\\mpaul_000\\Downloads\\a-small-practice.in') as f:
#    lines = f.readlines()

print (array)


brian = array()
broken = brian.partition(' ')
result = broken[2].count('0')
print (result)
```

Comment: `brian = array()` This line is your problem. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I'm trying to partition each entry (each line) of the input and then process the third part of that partition (everything after the " "). Every line in the input is now an entry in the array. Now I need to make that a sub-array, I guess? Partition creates an array, right?